# Get Futures Asset Balance Binance

Tags: python, binance

I tried searching for answers, but to no avail.

How do I get the balance of specific asset for a Futures Asset, for example, USDT?

```
[{'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'DOT', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'BTC', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'SOL', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'BNB', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'ETH', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'ADA', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'USDT', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'XRP', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'BUSD', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}]
```

My code:

```
acc_balance = client.futures_account_balance()
print(acc_balance)
for check_balance in acc_balance["accountAlias"]:
    if check_balance["asset"] == "USDT":
        usdt_balance = check_balance["balance"]
```

Error:

```
for check_balance in acc_balance["accountAlias"]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What's the mistake here? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`acc_balance` is a list, not a dictionary. You shouldn't index into it using a string.

Fixing this, we get the following:

```py
for check_balance in acc_balance:
    if check_balance["asset"] == "USDT":
        usdt_balance = check_balance["balance"]
        print(usdt_balance) # Prints 0.0000
```

Comment: Thank you so much. :) Could you be kind enough to give me your Discord?

Answer (score 1):

This means you cannot access your acc_balance list by a str index like "accountAlias". Usually for lists you can only refer to the index by int. However in your case you are using a dictionary in a list

```
[{'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'DOT', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'BTC', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'SOL', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'BNB', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'ETH', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'ADA', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'USDT', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'XRP', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'xx', 'asset': 'BUSD', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}]
```

So you can make this,

```
acc_balance = client.futures_account_balance()
```

as

```
acc_balance = client.futures_account_balance()[0]
```

such that your acc_balance is a dictionary and not a list anymore

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the `USDT balance` from the data structure if you are targetting `USDT`. You can loop through as answered previously if not.

```py
acc_balance = float(client.futures_account_balance()[6]['balance'])
```